# How do I convert a user defined Enumeration to a System.Enum in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

I have the following Enum defined (I have substituted the actual details with an example) :

```
Public Enum IceCream
    <Description("")> Uninitialized
    <Description("ChocolateChunk")> ChocolateChunk
    <Description("MintOreo")> MintOreo
End Enum
```

I have a function that I am trying to call:

```
Public Overloads Sub SetFood(ByVal food As String, ByRef NewVal As [Enum], ByRef OldVal As [Enum])
    OldVal = NewVal
End Sub
```

Here is the code I am using to try and call SetFood:

```
Public Property IceCreamEnum() As Enumerations.IceCream
        Get
            Return _IceCreamEnum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Enumerations.IceCream)
            If Value <> _IceCreamEnum Then
                SetFood("IceCreamEnum", Value, _IceCreamEnum)
            End If
        End Set
 End Property
```

I am getting this error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible SetFood can be called without a narrowing conversion
```

I believe the error is because I have defined IceCreamEnum and it can't convert it to the System.Enum, but I can't figure out how to correct it so that I can dynamically call this SetFood Function with different types of Enums I have defined (e.g. IceCreamEnum, BurgerEnum, etc.). Can anyone tell me how to convert the IceCreamEnum to a SystemEnum so I can call this function?

Comment: Is that SetFood method intended to be able to change any food to some other enum value?  It doesnt make much sense as is (and doesnt use the `food` param).

Comment: I don't want to show the actual code I'm writing so I tried to convert it to an example, but it's not a great example.  The idea is I have an overloaded method foo(string, old, new) where the old & new could be strings, ints, enums, etc.).  I want to call (foo, old, new) and have it go to the correct implimentation.  In this case I'm passing in user defined enums.

Comment: `Public Enum IceCream` defines a Type which is different than `[Enum]` even though the UnderLyingType is Enum.  If you are defining overloads, `Overloads Sub SetFood(ByVal food As String, ByRef NewVal As IceCream, ByRef OldVal As IceCream)`

Comment: It sounds like what I am going for isn't actually possible :)

Comment: It sounds like what you are going for *shouldn't* be possible.  It completely defeats the point of using enums.  If you want to "set a food" and there are different kinds of foods that produces various kinds of digestion and weight-gain problems then you need to use *polymorphism*, one of the pillars of object-oriented programming.  The Class keyword is the right kind of food for that, along with Overridable and Overrides.